# How do I set child element height to 100% not use javascript?

Tags: css

I have a html like the following, I want to set that SIDEBAR height to 100% but I tried many ways not always, can someone tell me how to do it?

p.s.
I hope that is automatic height, not be set that parent element height!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8' />
      <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .wrap {
        overflow: visible;
        height: auto;
      }
      .table {
        background: gray;
        list-style: none;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: inherit;
      }
      .left {
        background: green;
        display: table-cell;
        height: inherit;
      }
      .right {
        background: blue;
        display: table-cell;
        width: 300px;
        height: inherit;
      }
      .sidebar {
        background: red; 
        height: 100%; /* not working */
        margin: 0;
      }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <ul class="table">
        <li class="left">
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>more...</p>
        </li>
        <li class="right">
          <div class="sidebar">
            <p>link</p>
            <p>link</p>
            <p>link</p>
            <p>link</p>
            <p>link</p>
            <p>more..</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJpb6/

Answer (score 1):

Inititally, height 100% does nothing if the object doesn't know what 100% is.
The 100% depends on their parent. That's why on this particular case you must add it to the table, .wrap, body and html.

```
html, body {
     height:100%;
}

.wrap {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 100%;
}

.table {
    background: gray;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.table li {
      height:100%;
      display:table-cell;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YKqB8/

Comment: I hope that is automatic height, not be set that parent element height!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `height: inherit;` and you are inheriting height of a `div` which is set to auto, so when you use `height: 100%;`, but 100% of what? You need to set parent elements `height` to `100%` but since you want to make the side bar take up the blue space, you need to assign a fix height to the parent `div` like

```
.right {
    background: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    height: 330px;
 }
.sidebar {
    background: red; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cJpb6/1/)

If you want the containers to take up the entire page, than you need to make all containers height to 100% so that in this way the sidebar will be 100% of the 100% height of parent element

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cJpb6/2/)

Comment: I hope that is automatic height, not be set that parent element height!

Comment: @joe If you want to take up entire page, you might no need to worry about the height, if you don't than you need to have a fix height for parent container, that will explicitly explain to your side bar that 100% of x pixels